# HTML5 audio - currentTime attribute wrong after seeking on Safari

Tags: html, audio, safari

I wanted to sync audio music with some animation on the page.

I check audio currentTime with some template and starting an animation at the right moment.
All works fine except Safari. After a user uses seeking currentTime is not synchronized with an audio.

Example on codepen: https://codepen.io/vadymchyk/pen/pZVeaZ?editors=1111

Audio has a constant bitrate.
afinfo:

```
File: copy_ss120bpm_4minute_cla1.mp3

File type ID: MPG3
Num Tracks: 1

Data format:     2 ch,  44100 Hz, '.mp3' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1152 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame no channel layout.
estimated duration: 243.774667 sec
audio bytes: 5850592
audio packets: 9332
bit rate: 192000 bits per second
packet size upper bound: 1052
maximum packet size: 627
audio data file offset: 671
optimized
```

Who can tell what the problem is?

PS No problems on mobile Safari

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed on macOS 10.15 (Safari 13.0.3)
On macOS 10.14 and 10.13 (Safari 13.0.3) is still reproduced.